# How to show form data with confirm and cancel button before saving data in data base?

Tags: asp.net

How is it possible ? I have used ASP.Net text box and label controls.

Many Thanks

Comment: do it on Onclick event for save button

Comment: Welcome newbie. Please have a look at [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and then re-edit your post with some sample mark-up and code where you are facing some problem.

Comment: yes, but i would like show confirmation and cancel button again, please give any link if possible.

Comment: http://forums.asp.net/post/4321966.aspx

Comment: `OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to save this data?');"` add this in your button control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On save Button try to give `OnClientClick`

**aspx Save button**

```
   <asp:Button ID="btnsave" Text="Save" runat="server" OnClientClick="javascript: return test()" OnClick="serversave_click"></asp:Button>
```

**Javascript:**

```
function test() {
var empText = document.getElementById("<%=txtname.ClientID%>").value;
            if (confirm('Are You Certain to save this Name:'+ empText + '?')) { 
                return true;
            }
            else {
                return false;
            }

        }
```

Comment: Thanks, but with this message I also want to show form data(textbox and label value).

Comment: you mean to say in message you want to show that values ?

Comment: Yes, Name: ABC, Contact- 899283, Email-abc@gmail.com and then confirmation button and cancel button

Comment: I cant give whole three i can give example for how text box value can be shown in confirm so you can try remaining two !! , next time try to ask your question clearly so that you willl get prompt answer

Comment: Please give me how can I show text box value rest i'll implement. Thanks